# Webgl shader compilation errors in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, three.js

I'm learning three.js using this tutorial: http://demo.bkcore.com/threejs/webgl_tron_glow_seq.html.
The tutorial itself works fine, but my own code, based on it fails with errors like:

```
ERROR: 0:26: 'nuniform' : syntax error  Three.js:325
precision highp float;
#define MAX_DIR_LIGHTS 0
...
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;nuniform sampler2D tGlow;nvarying vec2 vUv;nvoid main() {nvec4 texel = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );nvec4 glow = texture2D( tGlow, vUv );ngl_FragColor = texel + vec4(0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.0) * glow * 2.0;n} 


ERROR: 0:62: 'nvoid' : syntax error  Three.js:325
precision highp float;
#define VERTEX_TEXTURES
...
varying vec2 vUv;nvoid main() {nvUv = vec2( uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y );ngl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );n}
```

etc.

It looks like browser (google chrome) doesn't parse properly strings with shaders encoded in them.
Errors appear in the code from three.js sources (minified version).

At a glance, the code is ok.

I'm just missing something, but I have no idea what exactly.

Any help?

Comment: So ... show us your shader source so we can say for definite where and how you've made a mistake :)

Comment: Paste the code where you define your shader.. the 'n' are definitely from line breaks but for some reason the slash is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like there are "\n"s in there causing problems.  It looks like the \ is removed but the n is left in.

Comment: Are you talking about all of the stray `n`s and `t`s in the error dump?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Indeed I am ... its very hard to tell without being able to see his shader source though ...

Comment: I noticed there seemed to be something odd going. That's a sharp eye you got there.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'll admit I thought the "t"s were just part of his naming scheme but in hindsight those could, indeed, be tabs :D

Comment: Well, I've found problem in my sources.
Thank to all of you! -)

Answer (score 0):

What you posted definitely looks wrong.

The 5th line has 'nuniform' which is not valid GLSL.

It looks like whatever minifier you used has a bug. If your shaders are in `<script>` tags you probably need to fix the minifier to only minify scripts that have no 'type' or have `type="javascript"` or `type="text/javascript"` because anything else is not JavaScript and should not be minified.